# How to find a dentry from an inode/pathname?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, inode

I am working on a module to read a files `xattributes` on open. I have hooked the `sys_open` and due to this I need to get the `dentry` of the file without opening the file. In brief I have the `inode` and the absolute path but having trouble to figure out; how to get a `dentry` from these. All comments are very much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556461/how-to-obtain-a-pathname-or-dentry-or-struct-file-from-a-given-inode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain a pathname or dentry or struct file from a given inode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8556461/608639)

Answer (score 3):

OK. Other answers didn't cover how to obtain a dentry from pathname/absolute path. The following code snippet could it.

```
    int ret = 0;
    struct path path;

    ret = kern_path("/proc/", LOOKUP_DIRECTORY, &path);
    if (ret)
            pr_err("Failed to lookup /proc/ err %d\n", ret);
    else {
            if (PROC_SUPER_MAGIC != path.mnt->mnt_sb->s_magic)
                    printk("BUG /proc is not mounted as Proc FS, magic %lx\n", path.mnt->mnt_sb->s_magic);
            path_put(&path);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my understating you are trying to get the **dentry path** from your driver module during the **open callback function** . If so; then before putting down the way I am adding the structure list which are required to access the the dentry information.

**`include/linux/fs.h`**

```
Struct file{
struct path             f_path;
};
```

**`include/linux/path.h`**

```
struct path {
           struct vfsmount *mnt;
           struct dentry *dentry;
  };
```

**`include/linux/dcache.h`**

```
struct dentry {
};
```

So you can do like this.

```
 static int sample_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
    { 
    char *path, *dentry,*par_dentry;
    char buff[256];
    dentry = file->f_path.dentry->d_iname;
    pr_info("dentry :%s\n",dentry);
    par_dentry = file->f_path.dentry->d_parent->d_iname;
    pr_info("parent dentry :%s\n",par_dentry);
    path=dentry_path_raw(file->f_path.dentry,buff,256);
    pr_info("Dentry path %s\n",path);
    }
```

Comment: We are actually trying to get the dentry struct from the file path. We need that to access the xattributes in the dentry that belongs to the file. We do not need the dentry path itself

Comment: @BenAtkinson I did not understand. ***What you mean by get the dentry structure***. Are you looking to get the the dentry structure form  your custom function like `custom_structure->mydent = file->f_path.dentry;` or something more?